# Why not use InMemory operational store?

Tags: identityserver4

There are some recommendations to replace InMemory operational store when going in production but what are actual roots of this suggestion?

I see these disadvantages of going with the default `IPersistedGrantStore`:

1. No persistance: when the server is restarted all users have to re-login
2. Sticky sessions are required, users can refresh tokens only at their instance

Are there other issues I may encounter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could find more problems with distributed services such as:

3. Reference tokens: reference tokens should be validated against the same instance that issued them when calling introspection from backend services.
4. Backend Token revokation: You'll need to call all instances to ensure revokation from backend.
5. Consent: you couldn't save consent preferences for users (rememeber consent).
6. Refresh tokens: you can't use long-lived refresh tokens among sessions and your user must be always present. You cannot use offline access.

Comment: Why 6? I use offline_access and everything is fine. Of course refresh tokens are wiped on server restart but it's ok.

Comment: I have only one instance of IdentityServer

Comment: If you only have one instance, the state of the app is much simpler. In memory storage can be a valid option then. But in your question you didn't mention this, so the answer I think should cover the possibility of the application being distributed.